Cannot view microsoft one drive api created docx
i used
PUT
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<id</drive/root:/test123.docx:/content
with content type "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" and data "Hello world"
It gives me a web url. However when i open it i get this screen

When i use download url to open it on desktop, it opens in word app.
I can open other drive docs which were manually created but not this auto generated one

When you open in the desktop app does it show the content?

seems reason is it takes only binary

It seems that the reason is it takes only binary not plain text in the data.
